# grafana: empty variable fields

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Grafana version: v8.3.3 (30bb7a93ca)

I've created my default prometheus datasource:

[image]

As you can see, I'm able to make queries and get some straightforward data.

By other hand, it's important to note it's getting `instance` and `application` field informed:

[image]

After that, I've imported [this](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/6756) really broad used dashboard for getting spring-boot metrics.

However, nothing seems to be gathering:

[image]

`instance` field selector is empty and other panels seems to not able to get data.

I've tried to inspect panel queries:

[image]

Next query is sent: `expr:"process_uptime_seconds{application="", instance=""}"`

I've tried to perform it directly on prometheus:

[image]

If I remove query filters:

[image]

If I perform it using filled query filters:

[image]

Problem is, why grafana instance and application fields are empty?

**EDIT:**

I've also took a look on `instance` dashboard variable:

[image]

As you can see, `Preview of values:` is only `None`.

After that, I've performed `instance` dashboard variable straigthforwardly on prometheus:

[image]

prometheus version is: `2.31.1`

Comment: Check dashboard variables, there are several and one is `instance`. Check the query used to obtain `instance` label values.

Comment: @anemyte, I've edited post with additional information. It seems there's some problem with `instance` dashboard variable query.

Comment: 'label_calues' is a grafana function, it won't work in Prometheus. The first argument of the function is a Prometheus query, which should return some metrics with instance label. If you have no such metric, replace it with another one that you have.